# Can I create a trapdoor in the boss rush room?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I have the Ehwaz rune. If I go into boss rush and take an item, can I use the rune to escape into the womb?

What if I had had "We Need To Go Deeper"?

Comment: Why would this be any different than a normal room?

Comment: The mechanic of how you get into and can get out of the boss rush room is different than a normal room in the game. So maybe the trapdoor is different and maybe it's not but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes you can](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/2nezqw/psa_having_the_we_need_to_go_deeper_active_item/), with both the rune of Ehwaz and We Need to Go Deeper! The two items are fuctionally identical and they both work in the Boss Rush room. Keep in mind anyway that there is a not so low chance (~10%) of getting a [Crawl Space](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Crawl_Space) instead of a passage to the next level when using these items.

A better way to be sure of getting out of the Boss Rush room is to use a teleporting item; this has also the added bonus of giving you a chance to get into the [I AM ERROR](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/I_AM_ERROR) room.